# Как вообще происходит программирование умного дома с нуля?

Tags: умный-дом

Весьма редкий вопрос, наверное :D Допустим есть ворота. Как их программно открыть из приложения на смартфоне? Что надо устанавливать, какой механизм? А каким способом его можно задействовать?

Просто интересно :)

Comment: ну в приводах ворот я не разбираюсь, наверняка какой нибудь движок с передачей. на входе предположим на одних выводах напряжение для открытия. на других для закрытия. сила тока там пличиная да и напряжение 220 небось. значит к ардуине цепляем 1-2 реле для переключения нагрузки и возможно пару датчиков на "полностью отрыты"/"закрыты", что бы вовремя выключить движок.  и пишем прошивку которая приняв какой то пакет по сети включит соответствующий вывод на котором нагрузка. в принципе можно даже по http команды получать. на смартфоне пишем програмку которая нужные пакеты посылает

Comment: на счет механизмов запросы в гугл "привод ворот" и "ardunio реле" отвечают в общем то на все вопросы по обвязке

Comment: Сначала надо разобратся - какая шина задействована. Наиболее распостранённая - knx, но есть и другие, например - Loxone, LCN-Bus.